# Удалять JButton по клику на неё и показывать её в другом месте

Tags: java, swing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно с помощью `swing` реализовать (`JLabel` или `JButton`), чтобы при нажатии на нее она удалялась и появлялась в другом месте и наоборот.

Например, есть колода карт развернутая веером, карту можно извлечь из середины колоды и поставить на стол нажав на нее, но если вам карта не понравилась кликаете на карту лежащий на столе и она должна вернуться в колоду, **но уже в конец колоды**.

Comment: 1. ruSO **не пишет** программы за кого-то, ruSO **помогает** с кодом. 2. Если честно, я вообще не понял, что вы хотите сказать. Я думаю, вам нужно четко и грамотно сформулировать свою мысль с учетом знаков пунктуации. 3. Если вам нужна написанная программа, обратитесь лучше на фриланс, там вам помогут за вознаграждение.

Comment: **Я прошу  помочь  с реализацией одной кнопки а не программы**

Comment: Я вам уже предоставил код с кнопкой ниже

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример, когда `JButton` удаляется и появляется в другом месте (на самом деле просто перемещается по `JPanel`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Заводим JFrame и его ContentPane - mainPanel
    JFrame fr = new JFrame("Test");
    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(null);
    mainPanel.setSize(300, 300);
    // Создаем кнопку, которая будет бегать по mainPanel
    JButton click = new JButton("Click!");
    mainPanel.add(click);

    Random r = new Random();
    Insets insets = mainPanel.getInsets();
    Dimension size = click.getPreferredSize();

    // Указываем случайное расположение кнопки
    click.setBounds(r.nextInt(200) + insets.left,
            r.nextInt(250) + insets.top,
         size.width, size.height);
    // При каждом нажатии на неё меняем расположение на случайное
    click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            click.setBounds(r.nextInt(200) + insets.left,
                r.nextInt(250) + insets.top,
                size.width, size.height);
        }
    });

    fr.setSize(310, 310);
    fr.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(310, 310));
    fr.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    fr.pack();
    fr.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: есть колода карт развернутая веером, карту можно извлечь из середины колоды и поставить на стол нажав на нее, но если вам карта не понравилась кликаете на карту лежащий на столе и она должна вернуться в колоду, но уже в конец колоды.

Comment: Если вам помог вопрос - отметьте его галкой. То, что вы просите - это гораздо более трудоемкое решение и заменой 1 строчки не получится. Можете задать его как новый вопрос.

Comment: Вы написали про колоду карт. А как вы сами представляете это себе? Про колоду карт - это уже фактически выполнение программы за вас, чем на ruSO не занимаются.

Comment: Только в `java` нет переменных типа `Карта`. Создайте свой класс Карты, добавьте туда метод перемещения. Почитайте про классы, поэкспериментируйте. Это же **ваша** первая проба, так зачем катать куски кода у других?

Comment: посмотри на код ниже

Comment: Ответы предназначены для ответов. Чтобы спросить - задавайте новый вопрос и приводите этот код. Да и сейчас пятница, мне лень смотреть)

Answer (score 1):

Как их перемещать на *стол* **sword12.setBounds(600, 112, 70, 102);** и обратно(на стол можно поставить токо 1 карту) если нажать на 2 карту она должна заменить 1

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.DefaultComponentFactory;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Scrollbar;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
```

public class Frame1 {

```
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame1 window = new Frame1();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Frame1() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1366, 728);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



JLabel sword1 = new JLabel("");
        sword1.setBounds(47, 112, 70, 102);
        Image img1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Karta1.png")).getImage();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        sword1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
        frame.getContentPane().add(sword1);

JLabel sword2 = new JLabel("");
        sword2.setBounds(398, 112, 70, 102);
        Image img2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Карта2.png")).getImage();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        sword2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
        frame.getContentPane().add(sword2);
```

Comment: Мне лень разбираться в твоем коде и править что-то еще)